# Retrofit give null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

> The first one with status code 500

```
{
"success": false,
"status": 500,
"message": "Salary detail not found."
```

}

> The second one with status code 200

```
{
"success": true,
"status": 200,
"result": {
    "salary": {
        "month_name": "October",
        "basic_salary": "Rs. 3,97,177.00",
        "overtime": "3987.5 (Hrs.)",
        "overtime_amount": "Rs. 1,56,696.00",
        "jobwork_amount": "Rs. 38,577.00",
        "net_salary": "Rs. 4,11,169.00"
    },
    "salary_list": [
        {
            "id": 279,
            "employee_name": "Rakesh [RAK]",
            "net_salary": "Rs. 10,911.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

> and this is model class

```
public class SalaryListModel {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
public String success;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
public int status_code;

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("result")
private Result result;


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public int getStatus_code() {
    return status_code;
}

public Result getResult() {
    return result;
}
```

> this is retrofit

```
Call<SalaryListModel> call = apiInterface.getSalaryList(new SessionManagerInd(activity).basicAuthRetrofit(), url);
    Log.e(TAG, "retrofitCall: URL: " + url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SalaryListModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SalaryListModel> call, Response<SalaryListModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling");
                if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 200) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling 200");



                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: else--");
                if (response.body().status_code == 500) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 500");

                } else if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 406) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 406");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: esle");
                }

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SalaryListModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

> the problem is when statuscode = 200 the is working fine  but when status code is 500 is gives error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: myapplication.erp.com.erpapp, PID: 5883
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int model.SalaryListModel.status_code' on a null object reference
                                                                            at cyberconsrots.com.sirgroup.sir_india.fragments.SalaryList$2.onResponse(SalaryList.java:195)
                                                                            at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
```

now i am not getting what i am doing wrong. Please help i am stuck with this from 2 hrs. status code is in Integer form

Comment: Http status code 500 is [Internal server error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) check for null in response.

Comment: the status code is self made getting respone from Rest Api

Comment: how can i get/or handle  status code = 500 is my retrofit respone

Comment: Can you provide full exception information.?

Comment: plz check above

Comment: try to change name of "status_code" variable name to "status" and check i think it will help.

Comment: In case of Http status code 500 your response object is null check for null in first statement then do the rest of validation .

Comment: if (response.body().status_code == 500) replace with this  if (response.body().getStatus_code()== 500)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have an error on your response, your response body is null.
You have to use the code from the Response and if you want to get the data from the error use the errorBody():

```
public void onResponse(Call<SalaryListModel> call, Response<SalaryListModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling");
                if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 200) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling 200");

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: else--");
                if (response.code() == 500) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 500");

                    //and if you want to parse your error body try this

                    /*
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        YourErrorClass error = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), YourErrorClass.class);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "onResponse error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }*/



                } else if (response.code() == 406) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 406");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: esle");
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: best answer... this solved my issue... thank you very much.

Comment: glad to help you :) , I don't know @ankitpatidar what is talking about :)

Comment: @diegoveloper you should read the question asked by him and the error code. it'll be if(response.body().getStatus_code== 500)

Comment: @diegoveloper status is comimg from API like he said                                                 {
"success": false,
"status": 500,   <-------(this is the status which is coming from API itself.)
"message": "Salary detail not found."
}          there is no need to check in unsuccessful in the above Question

Comment: if retrofit know the response is unsuccessful, then it won't be successful :) , you can't use this condition if (response.isSuccessful()) {

Comment: buddy he needs the result from API so if it's successful then he will get otherwise not. In my below code you can see ,that log will print UnSuccessful response if it isn't successful , if successful then response come from API(200,500)

Answer (score -1):

you should use it like that

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling");
            if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 200) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: calling 200");
            } else if (response.body().getStatus_code == 500) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 500");
            } else if (response.body().getStatus_code() == 406) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: 406");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: esle");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: UnSuccessful");
        }
```

Comment: if the response is Successful then it will never be 500,406, etc.

Comment: It'll come from API not Server side error , cause he has a status field in model class

Comment: if retrofit know the response is unsuccessful, then it won't be successful :) , you can't use this condition if (response.isSuccessful()) {